# I can't add an int to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, python-3.4

```
list == []

def MultiplesNumber(a):
    for i in range(1, a+1):
             if a % i == 0:
                    return i

list.append(MultiplesNumber(100))
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'
```

I can't add `i` to `list`, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things are wrong with your code:

- You are doing a  `list == []` which returns a True or False since `==` is a comparison operator. In this case it returns `False`. You need to use `=` to initialize a variable.
- `list` is the name of a built-in type in python, use something else as your variable name.

Fixing both of them :

```
alist = []

def MultiplesNumber(a):
    for i in range(1, a+1):
             if a % i == 0:
                    return i

alist.append(MultiplesNumber(100))
```

gives the correct output.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know **list** was a keyword. 
The == was a typo.

Comment: `list` is not a keyword. It is the name of the built-in list type, and so not a good variable name. But it's not forbidden in that role, just a bad idea.

Comment: @shaktimaan And the reason you were getting the error you were getting was, since you had the `==` typo, you were trying to call `append` on the list *type*, which was complaining because `append` is an instance method, and therefore requires an instance (`list` object) as the first argument. Hence the somewhat confusing error message you got.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is the inbuilt keyword which shadows your `list` variable. You need to assign a list to a variable not check its equality.

```
lst = []


def MultiplesNumber(a):
    return [x for x in range(1, a + 1) if a % 2 == 0]


lst.append(MultiplesNumber(100))
print(lst)
```